# Chebyshev's inequality, measure theory proof?

Tags: measure-theory

Can someone lead me to to the answer (that means you don't post the answer).

> Let $f$ be measurable with $f > 0$ almost everywhere. If $\int_E f = 0$ for some measurable set $E$, then $m(E) = 0$.

So I think by Chebyshev's inequality, we get for each $a \geq 0$,

$$\int_E f \geq a m(x \in E : f \geq a).$$

Select $a = 1/n$, then

$$0 = \int_E f \geq (1/n) m(x \in E : f \geq 1/n).$$

So $m(x \in E : f \geq 1/n) = 0 \implies m(\cup_{n\geq 1}E_n) = 0$

with $E_n = (x \in E : f \geq 1/n)$, but $ m(\cup_{n\geq 1}E_n) = m(E) = 0$ by assumption that $m(f > 0) = 0$

Comment: your proof seems correct. What is your question?

Comment: I feel like I made the wrong assumption. The assumption is actually that $m(f \leq 0) =0$ not $m(f > 0) = 0$

Comment: And Chebyshev's inequality demands $f$ to be nonnegative *everywhere*, not *almost everywhere*.

Comment: This is true. But your idea is still correct. Define $f^+:=\max\{0,f\}$. Then $\int_Ef=\int_Ef^+$, since $f=f^+$ almost everywhere. Now apply Chebyshev to $f^+$ as you did. You also need $m(f^+=0)=0$. Then $E=\bigcup_n\{f^+\geq1/n\}\cup\{f^+=0\}$.

Comment: Sorry, but what about $f^- = -\min(0,f)$? Why is $\min(0,f) = 0$? because we define $f = f^+ - f^-$

Comment: Oh wait, never mind because $f^- = 0$ almost everywhere (in fact, everywhere...)

Answer (score -1):

Assume that domain of f is a measurable set A.Since f>$0$ almost everywere then the set

B={x$\in$ A :f(x)<=$0$} has measure m(B)=$0$.Then
f>$0$ in A\B.Also E $\subseteq$ A and f>$0$ in E\B  .

So we apply Chebyshev.For $\frac{1}{n}$ we get that,
$\frac{1}{n}$*$m(E_{n})$ $\leq\ \int_E f\ $ with

$E_{n}$ = {x $\in$ E\B : f>= $\frac{1}{n}$ }.

Hence,$m(E_{n})$=$0$ and since the sequence of sets $(E_n)_{n=1}^\infty$
is increasing so  $\lim_{n\to\infty}(E_n) $ = m$(\cup_{n\geq 1}E_n)$=m(E/B)=$0$

We Conclude that m(E\B)=$0$ and m(B)=$0$.Therefore m(E)=$0$.